# How to test Google Custom Search for accuracy?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, google-custom-search

I've added a GCS script to a static blog based on Jekyll. Development is done on localhost, then pushed to a github pages location. The blog is a combination of posts & static pages.

Results thus far are very inconsistent. Some keywords return zero results despite being clearly visible in a document's body or title. The same keywords return different results when entered into a standalone GCS URL.

Any suggestions on test strategies for this type of problem?

Comment: I advice you to try : https://community.algolia.com/jekyll-algolia/

Comment: Thanks @DavidJacquel, I'm already trying Algolia too. Not sure which tool is better at this point.